# Prolog List Predicates

Tags: list, prolog

I need some help with three prolog predicates for checking and manipulating lists. I'm new to prolog and any help would be much appreciated.

The three predicates are:

- `double_up(+List1, -List2)` is true when `List2` has each element of `List1` twice. The query `double_up([a,b,c],X)` should give `X=[a,a,b,b,c,c]`. The order of the elements in the output list does not matter.
- `pivot(+List1, +Pivot, -Smaller, -GreaterEq)` is true when `Smaller` is the list of numbers in `List1` smaller than `Pivot`, and `GreaterEq` is the list of numbers in `List1` bigger than or equal to `Pivot`.
- `fancy_replace(+List, +Takeout,+Putin, -NewList, -Count)` is true when `NewList` is the same list as the input `List`, but where each `Takeout` element in the list is replaced with the `Putin` element. Count should be the number of Takeouts that got replaced. For example, the query `fancy_replace([9,10,1,9,2],9,0, X, C)` should give `X = [0,10,1,0,2]` and `C = 2`. The order of the elements in the output list does not matter.

Comment: I had the same reaction :) Hoping KGB doesn't alert on this...

Answer (score 1):

The simpler *pattern* to process lists in Prolog imposes a recursive predicate with 2 arguments, matching - conventionally - input and output data, and a base case, stopping the recursion, matching the empty list. Then

```
double_up([X|Xs], [X,X|Ys]) :- double_up(Xs, Ys).
double_up([], []).
```

This predicate it's a bit more *general* than what's required, because it works also in mode `double_up(-List1, +List2)`. For instance

```
?- double_up(L,[1,1,2,2]).
L = [1, 2].
```

To restrict its mode as required, I think it's necessary to *uselessly* complicate the code, moving that clean loop in a service predicate, and leaving double_up just to test the arguments:

```
double_up(I, O) :- is_list(I), var(O), double_up_(I, O).
double_up_([X|Xs], [X,X|Ys]) :- double_up_(Xs, Ys).
double_up_([], []).
```

pivot/4 could be 'one-liner' in SWI-Prolog:

```
pivot(List1, Pivot, Smaller, GreaterEq) :-
    partition(>(Pivot), List1, Smaller, GreaterEq).
```

like partition, foldl from library([apply](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.2%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/apply.html%27%29%29)) it's an easy inplementation of the last required predicate:

```
fancy_replace(List, Takeout, Putin, NewList, Count) :-
    foldl(swap_n_count(Takeout, Putin), List, NewList, 0, Count).
swap_n_count(Takeout, Putin, L, N, C0, C) :-
    (   L == Takeout
    ->  N = Putin, C is C0 + 1
    ;   N = L, C = C0
    ).
```

Answer (score -1):

to be honest, i hate prolog... even though it is fun and easy after you learn it

i think this is a good reference as I was having trouble understanding how prolog works couple weeks ago.
[what does the follow prolog codes do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994922/what-does-the-follow-prolog-codes-do)

anyway.. this is the answer for your first problem; Hopefully you could solve the rest yourself :D

```
double([]).
double([H|[]], [H,H|[]]).
double([H|T],[H,H|T1]):- double(T, T1).
```

btw, this might not the only solution...but it works

Comment: I cannot think what you could do to a developer of a ugly and complex language (like... choice one :)

Comment: The second clause is subsumed by the third clause, you can remove it. Also, you can write `[H|[]]` simply as `[H]`, and `[H,H|[]]` as `[H,H]`.